# Lraravel Send the same AJAX request from the list of the posts and from one post

Tags: laravel

There is page with url `mysite/dashboard` with the lists of the posts

route

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

method

```
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::latest('published_at')->unpublished()->paginate(20);
    return view('dashboard.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

every post in the list has button **Publish**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-publish-post">Publish</button>
```

route for method

```
Route::post('publish', 'PostsController@publish');
```

js script

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-publish-post', function(){
var $btn = $(this);
var post_id = $(this).closest('.post').data('post-id');

$btn.prop('disabled', true);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'publish',
    data: {'id' : post_id},
    dataType: 'json',                   
    success: function(response){ 
        if(response.success) {
          $btn.closest('.post').remove();
        }
        if(response.fail) {

        }
        $btn.prop('disabled', false); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
        $btn.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
});
```

method in `PostsController`

```
   public function publish(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->get('id');
        $published = Post::where('id', $id)
            ->update(['is_published' => 1]);
        if ($published) {
            return Response::json(array(
              'success' => true
            ));
        }
        return Response::json(array(
            'fail' => true
        ));
    }
```

For every post in the list all code works just fine.

But also I can open every one post

route

```
Route::get('dashboard/posts/{id}', 'DashboardController@show');
```

method in `DashboardController`

```
public function show($id) {
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    return view('dashboard.show', compact('post'));
}
```

and the post also has **Publish** button, but for one post js code doesn't work becase it tries to send AJAX request to url `mysite/dashboard/posts/publish` (not `mysite/publish`) and of course fails. How to make my code works for the list of the posts and for one post both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the AJAX request is not sending the request to `mysite/publish`, then the easy fix is to use the following url relative to the site root: `/publish`

So, you just need to change `url: 'publish',` to `url: '/publish',`